# how do I delete lines and columns together using awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I am super new here, I am trying to remove a few rows (header) and some columns (not wanted fields) from a data file, I found this:
if I use:

```
awk 'NR>2' text.txt >newtext.txt
```

I can basically get rid of the first two lines.
if I use:

```
awk '{for(z=2;z<=13;z++)$z="";$0=$0;$1=$1}1' text.txt > newtext.txt
```

I get the desired columns.
However, I cannot do them together. How do I combine two commands?
How could I do this in an efficient way?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help with formatting from @Diligent Key Presser, appreciate your patience if the question is naive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
 awk '{if (NR>2) { print $0; print $1  }} ' text.txt >newtext.txt
```

The if condition will make sure that first 2 lines are not output.
And using print command inside if will output only your desired column

`Note:`I suggest you to use print command inside awk to output text for redirecting to file

Comment: It looks like {print $0; print $1} makes two columns into one column in the output file? Am I missing something here?

Comment: You can use `print $1,$2`. Here `,` is called output field seperator 'OFS' while tells awk that user wants space between $1 and $2. More on this you can read here https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Output-Separators.html

Comment: Also, `print $0` will print the whole line. From you're question, it seems you want to print specific columns.

Comment: Yes, I realized that. Also, if I put "if (NR>2){...}", my cygwin says"awk: cmd. line:1: if (NR>2) { print $1,$2  }
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ syntax error"
without if() as awk 'NR>2{print $1}' file > output @karakfa works.

Comment: This gives error because you need to put if statement inside `{}`. I have updated my answer

Comment: Thank you very much. I got all the function I need. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @Ed Morton. Thanks for the book reference. Will surely go through the book - 'GAWK: Effective AWK Programming'

Answer (score 2):

you can combine them,

```
$ awk 'NR>2{print $1}' file > output
```

note that in your second script `$0=$0;$1=$1` is useless.  Since you're nulling the columns 2-13, perhaps you meant to print only 1?

Comment: "$0=$0;$1=$1" Removed. Thank you! I am still trying it out to get this combine to work.

Comment: Thank you again, your answer helped and is correct. My problem get solved. Appreciate a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding a BEGIN clause that skips the first 2 lines:

```
awk 'BEGIN {getline; getline}'
```

Comment: Absolutely not. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline if you're ever considering using getline for when/how to use it correctly.

Comment: I agree that it is an absolutely procedural approach, but it works and may enjoy some performance advantages.

Comment: Q) How would you modify it to work on multiple files? A) Complete rewrite. Q) How would you modify it to only skip lines that contain X? A) Complete rewrite. Q) Why does every minor requirements change require a complete rewrite? A) Because it's the wrong approach. Optimize for performance at the expense of other design considerations if/when it proves to be necessary.